# Make image center aligned

Tags: html, css

I want to make the images on [this](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/mntextile/news-and-events/) page centre aligned. I have tried below solution but it does not work in my case. Please guide.
**PASSWORD: inspurate123**

**Solution:**

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

My code:

```
<div class="title_area" style="float:left;">
    <h1 class="post_title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </h1>
    <br>

    <?php the_content(); ?>                     
</div>   
</article>
<?php get_template_part('share_this');?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why use `style="float:left;`

Comment: What images do you mean?

Comment: @torazaburo: The big images displayed in posts.

Comment: The link you give is password-protected. Please paste a screenshot into the question so people don't have to consult off-site resources to understand your question.

Comment: @torazaburo: Provided the password.

Comment: it says in incorrect password boss!

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa:inspurate123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Try it:-

```
.wp-caption.alignnone{
     margin:0 auto
 }
.title_area img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Hope it works for you.

[image]

Comment: I can clearly see from the image that it is not aligned in the middle.

Comment: `.wp-caption.alignnone{margin:0 auto}` add it

Comment: `.title_area img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
 /*   width: 90%; */
}` remove width

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove `float`

you can do it like below

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/q2bm79t2/

```
img{
    margin:0 auto;

    }

.imageReplace{
    text-align:center

}
```

Html

```
<div class="imageReplace">
    <img src="http://drublic.de/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/rotate-images.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: `text-align` does nothing on an image tag.

Comment: @  torazaburo i wanted to mention like above, thank you for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:inline-flex (CSS3)

add this to the `body{display:inline-flex; width:100%;}`

now remove the padding from your login.

It's css3, some browsers won't support it.

Comment: Including anything below IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it worked

```
img{
display:block !important;
clear:both;
margin:0 auto;
}
```